# Trying to run Appium test in android 7.0, but just Appium settings and Unlocker app get installed and test does not run

Tags: appium

Following is the link to my code and error sin appium console 
and eclipse console:

[Link to the code and error in eclipse console and appium console](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-QBwnCjr6U9Xy1rc1BIOGRibkk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Appium logs, it has this line in there -

```
info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version
```

This means that version is not the correct property name. You have to change it to `platformVersion`. Try changing it and see it it works. The line of code would be like this -

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
```

Also, there is no need to provide the browser name, as you are not using it anywhere. But that shouldn't affect the test script execution in any way.

You can also check this article which shows the capabilities you can use to launch an app - [Appium Script to Launch App](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/first-appium-test-script/)

Comment: I tried this but I am still not able to run the code.

Comment: Appium settings and unlocker get installed and then nothing happens.

Comment: Can you share the error logs which you get after making the above change?